# Javascript - Add a comma after every line break

Tags: javascript, php

I have a .txt file full of strings that look like the ones beneath.
I need to add a comma at the end of every line.
At the moment it looks like this:

```
name,age ----> usa
name,age ----> uk
name,age ----> de
```

And after it should look like this:

```
name,age ----> usa,
name,age ----> uk,
name,age ----> de,
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, take a stab at it, and *if* you get stuck, post a question saying what research you've done and what attempt you've made to solve the problem.

Comment: A text file - how are you reading that?

Comment: i am just copying and pasting the string into the console at the moment

Comment: Have a think about it. `\n` is a new line character. You can `replace` it using the "global flag", although the last line won't be affected.

Comment: You have tagged the question with PHP so why not use PHP to read and process the textfile?

Comment: Yes i could, i just dont seem to understand how to do that

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex

```
var str = `name,age ----> usa
name,age ----> uk
name,age ----> de`;
var str2  = str.replace(/(\n)/g,",\n") + ",";
```

Comment: this does not work. the result of str2 is:
`'name,age ----> usa,\nname,age ----> uk,\nname,age ----> de,'`

Answer (score 0):

Yes use regex, but the above answer is incorrect (it results in `\n` at the start of each line).

```
var str = `name,age ----> usa
name,age ----> uk
name,age ----> de`;

var str2  = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ',');
```

The output will be:

```
'name,age ----> usa,    name,age ----> uk,    name,age ----> de'
```